# android pop out (zoom) view on focus

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a group of views, which I want to 'pop-out' of the screen when focused; the sort of thing you might see in a menu on a video game, for example.

To achieve this I am adding an onfocusChaned listener to these views which runs a zoomIn animation on focus, and a zoomOut animation on losing focus:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup base = (ViewGroup) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridtest, null);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) base.getChildAt(0);

    this.animZoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
    this.animZoomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomout);
    int x=0;

    for(View child:this.getViews(container))
    {
        ImageView i = (ImageView) child;
        i.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

        if(x==0) { i.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); x++; }
        else if(x==1) {i.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); x++; }
        else if(x==2) {i.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); x=0; }

        i.setTag(GridActivity.TAG_EMPTY);
        i.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if (hasFocus)
                {
                    v.startAnimation(GridActivity.this.animZoomIn);
                }
                else
                {
                    v.startAnimation(GridActivity.this.animZoomOut);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    setContentView(base);
}
```

zoomin.xml:

```
<scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:zAdjustment="top"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="1.2"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="200" />
```

zoomout.xml:

```
<scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:zAdjustment="bottom"
android:fromXScale="1.2"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.1"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:duration="50" />
```

This works in so far as the views zoom in and out correctly, however the z-ordering of the views doesn't change... so the 'popped out' view is overlapped by the (smaller) view immediately to its right.

[image]

I have tried using v.bringToFront() but that appears to move the focused view to the end of the parent layout, rather than actually re-order it z-wise.

(edit)
This is the effect I'm trying to duplicate
[image]

Comment: did you try FrameLayout with gridtest layout?

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: what is your parent layout in gridtest.xml?
FrameLayout allows placing views over other views, so bringToFront() shouldn't move the position of your view then,
Looking at your screenshot, I guess the parent is LinearLayout

Comment: a frame layout is not appropriate for this situation... according to google: "Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other"

Comment: Have you resolved this one? I also have the same problem with RecyclerView and don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Sorry this was never resolved :(

Comment: In API level 21+, we can use ViewCompat.setElevation() to handle this case, but I don't know how to make it work with Kitkat.